# Does the Oathbow count as a magical source of damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons

Does the [Oathbow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/oathbow) count as a magical source of damage to bypass resistance/immunity to nonmagical attacks?

While it is in the Magic Items section of the DMG, it does not actually state  that it is a magical weapon like they did with the [Sword of Sharpness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/sword-of-sharpness).

Comment: Related: [What makes a weapon magical, for the purpose of immunity to non-magical weapons?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84511)

Comment: I was going to answer this but I see now that it is marked as a duplicate. Important things in this argument: A Bow is a weapon, and attunement is limited to magic items, thus Oathbow is a magic weapon. I don't think that the other question and answer use this logic though. Feel free to add it to your new answer over there.

Comment: @Slagmoth That's a good point, but to counter the Moon-touched weapons from Xanathar's don't require attunement and also don't state they're magical. I'm worried that adding that (which was a great idea) will muddy the issue more than it needs to.